# Using three numbers sum one to three of them yield all numbers ranging from 1-15

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I was asked this question today in a junior math class and I couldn't find a reasonable solution even trying rigorously.

The question states that you must find three numbers such that they add to every number between one and fifteen. You may sum at most three numbers together.

So for example if you pick the set
$$1,2,3$$ You yield the solution
$$[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$$ 
if you pick
$$1,2,5$$
you yield
$$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15$$

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call our set of three numbers $S$. Clearly, $S$ must contain $5$ (otherwise, even picking the largest number in $S$ three times will not be enough to obtain $15$).

Now we need to figure out the other two numbers. It is also obvious that our set must contain $1$ (otherwise, picking even the smallest number in $S$ will not be small enough to obtain $1$).

Okay, now we have $1$ and $5$.  With some inspection (or maybe just trial-and-error), you can determine that the last missing number is $4$. This is true because, otherwise, we will not be able to get $14$ by only picking three digits.

Therefore, the answer is $S = \{1, 4, 5\}$. We can make sure this works by writing each number between $1$ and $15$ with at most three of these numbers:

$$1 = 1$$
$$2 = 1 + 1 $$
$$3 = 1+1+1 $$
$$4 = 4 $$
$$5 = 5 $$
$$6 = 5 + 1 $$
$$7 = 5 + 1 + 1 $$
$$8 = 4 + 4 $$
$$9 = 5 + 4 $$
$$10 = 5 + 5$$

$$11 = 5 + 5 + 1 $$
$$12 = 4+4+4 $$
$$13 = 5 + 4 + 4$$
$$14 = 5+5+4 $$
$$15 = 5+5+5 $$

Comment: Another start is that there's 10 ways to select 3 to get a distinct sum, etc.

Comment: Thankyou!
The method I was using obviously had to contain 1, then it also had to contain either 2,3, or 4 to get 4. 
I proved that 2 and 3 were not possible by listing y,y+1,y+1+1,y+1+z,y+2z,2y,2y+1,2y+z,3y and the same for z(canceling out the duplicates) then picking y to be 2 3 or 4 and showing that there were not enough equations remaining with unique numbers to give me 15 solutions. I missed 5 with four so thankyou